# Jquery UI sortable call two functions on stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery ui sortable to sort a table and I need to call two functions when the sort event stops. I've managed to call one function but I'm having difficulties to call two and I need the second function only to happen when the first is complete.

This is what I hyave right now:

```
  var sortPosition = function(event, ui) {
      var updatePosition = 1;

      $( "tbody tr" ).map( function(){
          $(this).find('.position span').text(updatePosition);
          updatePosition++;
      });
  }

  $("table tbody").sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      start: function(e, ui ){
             ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
      },
      helper: fixHelper,
      stop: sortPosition
  }).disableSelection();
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
  var sortPosition = function(event, ui) {
      var updatePosition = 1;

      $( "tbody tr" ).map( function(){
          $(this).find('.position span').text(updatePosition);
          updatePosition++;
      });
  }

  var savePosition = function(event, ui) {
    alert(2);
  }

  $("table tbody").sortable({
      placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
      start: function(e, ui ){
             ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight());
      },
      helper: fixHelper,
      stop: function(e, ui) {
            sortPosition;
            savePosition;  
          }
  }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: this should work you just need to call the function not reference it should be `sortPosition(); savePosition();`however @Trevors example will ensure your first method executes before the 2nd. however the default behavior without callbacks/async is that it would wait to call save till after update is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about calling `savePosition` at the end of your `sortPosition` function?

```
var sortPosition = function(event, ui) {
  var updatePosition = 1;

  $( "tbody tr" ).map( function(){
      $(this).find('.position span').text(updatePosition);
      updatePosition++;
  });
  savePosition();
}

$("table tbody").sortable({
    ....
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        sortPosition();  
    }
}).disableSelection();
```